# How to add Custom Script Codes in Nuxt Head and Body dynamically?

Tags: google-analytics, nuxt.js, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

I need to add Tracking Codes in my app like

1. Google Analytics
2. Google Tag Manager
3. Facebook Pixel

I've seen that there are packages for the 3 of them. But these packages need the ID to be passed in the configuration part.

In my use case I've to make an API request and then decide which tags to add, also I might be adding lot of other scripts dynamically. What's the right way to append customer script codes like these in either Head or Body tags?

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-DYXWW9MXXX"></script>
<script>
   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
   gtag('js', new Date());

   gtag('config', 'G-DYXWW9MXXXX');
</script>
```

Can I pass this entire script as a variable and append it to the Head or Body according to the Script requirement? What's the right way to achieve this in Nuxt?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, here is how I solved it.

```
    setup() {

            let ga = "G-DYXWW9ABCD"
            let gtm = "GTM-KJXABCD"
            let fbPixel = "263354452112345" 

            onMounted(async () => {


                if (!process.server) {
                        const script = document.createElement("script");
                        script.onload = gTagLoaded;
                        script.type = "text/javascript";
                        script.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id="+ga;
                        document.head.appendChild(script);
                    } else {
                        gTagLoaded();
                    }

                    (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
                    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
                    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
                    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer',gtm);


                    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
                    {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
                    n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
                    if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
                    n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
                    t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
                    s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
                    'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
                    fbq('init', fbPixel);
                    fbq('track', 'PageView');
                    

                   var gtmScript = document.createElement('div'); // is a node

                   gtmScript.innerHTML =  `<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=${gtm}" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>`

                   document.body.appendChild(gtmScript) 

                   var fbPixelScript = document.createElement('div')

                   fbPixelScript.innerHTML = `<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
                    src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=${fbPixel}&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
                    /></noscript>`

                    document.body.appendChild(fbPixelScript) 


            })


            function gTagLoaded(event = null) {

                window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
                gtag('js', new Date());

                gtag('config', ga);
            }
        
    }
```

Comment: Won't the <noscript> part have to be appended to app.html directly? Because if JS is disabled (which is the purpose of having a noscript), it can't run the JS to create the <noscript>